# Need another dropdown menu when first drop down selects a value using spring tag in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, jsp

I have my jsp file ,in which I need 2 drop downs.If I select 1st drop down ,based on value,it should display another drop down.
I am using springMVC and jstl in jsp.

here is my code for generate.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sp" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Generation</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectEmp").on('change',function(){
    
     if(this.val =='2')
     {
      $("#dept").css('display','block');
      $("#dept").show();
     }
     else
     {
      $("#dept").hide();
     }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown generate-file">Type :<sp:select id="selectEmp" path="type" name="selectEmp"> 
    <option value="1">All</option>
      <option value="2">Department</option>
      <option value="3">Individual</option>
      </sp:select></div><br/><br/>
    <div class="dropdown generate-file" id="dept" style="display:none;">
     Department:<sp:select  path=""><span class="caret"></span>
      <option value="">R and D</option>
      <option value="">Development</option>
      <option value="">Sales</option>
      <option value="">Admin</option>
      <option value="">HR</option>
      <option value="">Marketing</option>
      <option value="">CRM</option>
      <option value="">Finance</option>
      </sp:select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("#dept).css('display','block');`. Missing a quote here.

Comment: Even if i do that, it is not working..:(

Comment: I also don't see where you command the dropdown to show. You make the `input` show, but not `<div class="dropdown generate-file"  style="display:none;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$(this).val() == '2'`.

```
$dept = $("#dept");
$(this).val() == '2' ? $dept.show() : $dept.hide();
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#selectEmp").on('change', function() {
    $dept = $("#dept");
    $(this).val() == '2' ? $dept.show() : $dept.hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown generate-file">Type :
  <select id="selectEmp" name="selectEmp">
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="2">Department</option>
    <option value="3">Individual</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="dropdown generate-file" id="dept" style="display:none;">
  Department:
  <select path=""><span class="caret"></span>
    <option value="">R and D</option>
    <option value="">Development</option>
    <option value="">Sales</option>
    <option value="">Admin</option>
    <option value="">HR</option>
    <option value="">Marketing</option>
    <option value="">CRM</option>
    <option value="">Finance</option>
    <select>
</div>
```